# Unable to use GridView Control from Windows Community Toolkit

Tags: c#, winui-3

I'm having a problem getting the GridView control from the Windows Community Toolkit working in my WinUI project. I've added the Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Control nuget package, which has installed successfully, and I can see it added to the correct project in solution explorer.

My XAML (some irrelevant code removed for brevity) is as follows:

```
<Window
    x:Class="SampleApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" SizeChanged="SizeChanged"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
        (other controls/content removed for brevity)
        <controls:DataGrid (code removed for brevity)>
        </controls:DataGrid>
</Window>
```

When trying to add the control to the XAML file, the line     `xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"` gives the compiler error:

> XLS0429   Undefined namespace. The 'using' URI refers to a namespace
> 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls' that could not be found.

...and the line starting `<controls:DataGrid` gives the compiler error:

> XLS0414   The type 'controls:DataGrid' was not found. Verify that you
> are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced
> assemblies have been built.

I've been following examples such as [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/communitytoolkit/getting-started), but I'm not getting anywhere.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used the tag 'winui-3' yet your package is for UWP / WinUI 2.

Pick one and try again.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls/

Comment: Many thanks. That explains a lot. As you might be able to tell, it's my first venture into WinUI 3, I'm coming from backend/WinForms development (and I've been out of the game for a couple of years).